# App crashes when deleting data from SQLite in iPhone5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, iphone-5

I developed a SQLite database when application **"didFinishLoading"** database cleared and calls a web service to get data and insert it into the database. It's working fine in all iPhone and iPad devices, but on iPhone5, it crashes when deleting data from the database.

Here, `tableNamesArray` means tables in SQLite.

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [tableNamesArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM %@", [tableNamesArray objectAtIndex:i]];

        NSLog(@"querySQL %@", querySQL);

        // SELECT QuationID,Quation FROM QuationsTable WHERE GroupID="Group0"

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
        }

        if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE )
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }

    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Any chance you're trying to update a file in the app bundle?

Comment: yes @H2CO3, i changed Dispaly Name

Comment: mr.H2C03, first time when i created DB file for sqlite adding with 3 tables, after that i deleted that file and add some more tables to the same file. again added to the app.

Comment: You can't modify files in the app bundle. It is (for very obvious security reasons) read-only.

Comment: Ok @H2CO3, then what is the solution for that

Comment: Use a writable location?

Comment: i can't understood Mr.H2C03

Comment: but its working fine in all other device except iPhone5

Answer (score 0):

Use This function to copy your database into cache directory.

```
-(void)createDBcopy:(NSString*)fileName
{
    // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
    BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *DBPath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    //DBPath = [DBPath stringByAppendingString:@".sqlite"];
    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:DBPath];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) return;

    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem
    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:DBPath error:nil];

    [fileManager release];

}
```

And use it as:

```
[yourClassObjectWhereTheMethodIsWritten createDBcopy:@"yourDB.sqlite"];
```

You should use it at didFinishLaunchWithOption in Appdelegate.